# Display a sublist using the list option selected

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am creating an ecommerce website in Java in which I have categories such as clothing, books, electronics, etc. What I wish is that when I choose a category, e.g. electronics, I should get a list with sub-options such as mobiles, TV, iPod, etc. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a **Categories** class with a static `getSubCategories()` method which returns a set of sub-categories for each possible category:

*Categories.java*

```
import java.utils.List;
import java.utils.Arrays;

Class Categories { 

    private final statis Categories categories = null;

    private Map<String, List<String>> subCategories = null;

    private Categories() { 
        subCategories = new HashMap<>();
        subCategories.put("eletronics", Arrays.asList("mobiles", "TV", "iPod"));
    }

    public static Categories getInstance() {
        if (categories == null) { 
            categories = new Categories();
        }
        return categories;
    }

    public static getSubCategories(String category) {
        return subCategories.get(category);
    }
}
```

Assuming that you've a **jsp** page which handle the user input, you can print the subcatgories of a category as follows:

*action.jsp*

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" %>
<%
    String category = request.getParameter("category");
    List<String> subCategories = Categories.getSubCategories(category);
%>
<html>
<body>
//Print the sub-categories
Subcategories are : <%=subCategories%>
</body>
```

Comment: I have developed the jsp page for the primary list.Where should i put this code?